# Quais são os livros recomendados sobre programação e Inteligência Artificial para iniciantes?

Tags: inteligência-artificial

Eu gostaria de saber quais livros vocês recomendariam para quem quer aprender Inteligência Artificial e já sabe programar em alguma linguagem?

Comment: Eu recomendaria [Essentials of Metaheuristics](http://cs.gmu.edu/~sean/book/metaheuristics/Essentials.pdf) como um material introdutório a IA.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Recomendo este livro: **Programming Collective Intelligence: Building Smart Web 2.0 Applications**
mas não sei se existe em português.

É mais sobre machine learning (aprendizado de máquina) do que Inteligência Artificial. É sobre um sub-campo da Inteligência Artificia só mas tem muitos exemplos práticos, é ótimo se você quiser começar a programar rapidamente.